# django with nginx uwsgi bad gateway 502

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

i want to run django with nginx i followed this [instructions](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) and in

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/cartoview_one

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///root/cartoview_project/mysite.sock; # for a file socket    }

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 2048M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /root/cartoview_project/uploaded;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /root/cartoview_project/static;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /root/cartoview_project/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

then created symlink using:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/cartoview_one /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

and in project folder `mysite_uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
project = cartoview_project
chdir           = /root/cartoview_project
module          = %(project).wsgi:application
home            = /root/env
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /root/cartoview_project/mysite.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum          = true
http-socket = 0.0.0.0:80
```

project structure :

> ```
> .
> |-- apps
> |-- cartoview_project
> |   |-- __init__.py
> |   |-- __init__.pyc
> |   |-- local_settings.py
> |   |-- local_settings.pyc
> |   |-- local_settings.py.sample
> |   |-- settings.py
> |   |-- settings.pyc
> |   |-- urls.py
> |   |-- wsgi.py
> |   `-- wsgi.pyc
> |-- default_oauth_apps.json
> |-- initial_data.json
> |-- manage.py
> |-- mysite_uwsgi.ini
> `-- uwsgi_params
> ```

when i try to access website with myip this message appear :

> 502 Bad Gateway
>
> nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

error.log :

> 2017/02/06 09:46:41 [crit] 6867#6867: *1 connect() to
>   unix:///root/cartoview_project/mysite.sock failed (13:
>   Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://unix:///root/cartoview_project/mysite.sock:", host:
>   "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Update :

i removed `http-socket` and run the following command `/root/env/bin/uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini` and `mysite.sock` appeared in project then  restart nginx but nothing changed.

```
:~/cartoview_project# stat mysite.sock
  File: 'mysite.sock'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 17172079    Links: 1
Access: (0666/srw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-02-06 10:44:56.188168371 +0100
Modify: 2017-02-06 10:44:56.188168371 +0100
Change: 2017-02-06 10:44:56.188168371 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Machine : vps(Ubuntu 16.04)  User: root

**Solved :** 
by changing `include     /root/cartoview_project/uwsgi_params` to `include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;`

Comment: You can use this command to run your application in backend in production with uwsgi `uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8134 --wsgi-file UniservedWebsite/wsgi.py &` and refer your nginx to `0.0.0.0:8134` and add `http-timeout`

Answer (score 1):

From the description, it looks like you haven't run your uwsgi process - a 502 error at this point means that nginx is passing the response through correctly, but there's nothing for it to connect *to*, or it's not getting the correct response.

`which uwsgi` will give you the path for the appropriate uwsgi (do this inside your virtualenv if you're running one).

e.g.

`/root/cartoview_project/uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini`

You should take the `http-socket` config variable out of uwsgi though - nginx is listening on port 80, and passing it through to your `.sock` file created by your uwsgi app.

Comment: i removed `http-socket` and run the following command `/root/env/bin/uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini` and restart nginx but nothing changed note: `mysite.sock` appeared in project

Comment: Is wsgi definitely running?  Check in top.  If you run `stat` on your `mysite.sock` file what user/group and permissions do you get?

Comment: stat result in question

Comment: Did you have it working off ports before you moved to socket? It looks mostly ok, but I think there's something odd happening when you pass the django upstream through - try the [section with ports first](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site) if you haven't already. For reference [here is my nginx conf from a production site](https://gist.github.com/iamwithnail/5f61031482f72bb4f47db84dba14828d) Maybe the params need to come first?

Comment: I've added an anonymised version of our uwsgi.ini there as well.